# Next.js: console gets cleared automatically, preventing me from seeing the output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js

in my Next.js app, I have a form defined like this:

```
  <form onSubmit = {
    async() => await getCertificate(id)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
  }>
```

The problem is that when an error occurs, it displays for a split second in the console and then the console is instantly cleared (thus preventing me from reading the error).

I tried adding `.catch(e => console.error(e))` to the end of the call, but this doesn't fix the issue.

How can I prevent the console from getting automatically cleared like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable `Preserve Log` in your Developer Console.

Steps:
Developer Console -> Setting Icon (right side) -> Preserve Log

onSubmit accepts a function. Rewrite your code as

```
<form onSubmit = {() => {
    async() => await getCertificate(id)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
  }}>
```

Also form submission resets the page. In case you don't want this behaviour then you can use preventDefault like this.

```
<form onSubmit = {(event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    async() => await getCertificate(id)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
  }}>
```